# Trying to enter the UK with an EEA Spouse without any visa?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, family

My wife applied for an EEA Family Visa 2 weeks ago, and today she received notice that she has been refused. The letter said that we did not provide enough evidence of our relationship, such as photos or documents that show that we have lived together. We can appeal the decision, but this will take time. We also want to re-apply but the earliest available date is 24 December and we don't want to wait that long.

We are thinking about meeting in France and going by bus to the UK, bringing with us the proof of our relationship.

What is the risk of my wife being refused entry at a land border point?

Comment: You're not generally supposed to need to show photographs or evidence of having lived together unless there is reason to suspect that you are in a marriage of convenience.  The ECO has a *burden of proof* to show that such a suspicion is reasonable.  Did you marry recently, or is there other reason to suspect that your marriage is not genuine?  If not, get in touch with the Entry Clearance Manager at the consulate.  (Also, if you have a child together, the refusal is *clearly contrary to policy.)*

Comment: (We've had at least one person post on this site that the UK immigration officers in France admitted them with some disbelief that they didn't get the EEA family permit, so if you can try that route, it's probably a good bet.)